# Routing internet traffic via the vpn interface

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, iproute

I have a wifi dongle where I have three interfaces `wlan0` (default route), `uvpn0`(VPN interface) and `usb0`(interface between the host machine and the dongle).

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr DA:CE:84:EA:A3:E3  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d8ce:84ff:feea:a3e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:123259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8718640 (8.3 MiB)  TX bytes:150323744 (143.3 MiB)

uvpn0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.87.0.3  P-t-P:10.87.0.3  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING  MTU:1420  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:368 (368.0 B)  TX bytes:1552 (1.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:17:69:EC:A2:E4  
          inet addr:10.117.176.210  Bcast:10.117.176.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:143066201 (136.4 MiB)  TX bytes:6608011 (6.3 MiB)
```

Currently, the internet traffic is go through the `wlan0` interface. I want the internet traffic to go through the VPN server `10.87.0.1`. I tried the following things

1. Change the default route by adding the following command

```
ip route add default via 10.87.0.1 dev uvpn0
```

The moment I added the above command. I am not able to ping to the VPN server from the dongle.

2. I also added an IP rule

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.117.176.0/24 -o uvpn0 -j MASQUERADE
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to dest nat to ethernet of vpn.

Comment: masquerade is source nat, not dest nat.

Comment: However finally you need masqerade.

Comment: Is this OpenVPN or some paid ones?